# SSIS Script Component Not Logging

Tags: ssis, c#, log

How can I log from within an SSIS Script Component?

I am using the below code, which I believe should work.

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
    this.Log("Entering PreExecute()", 0, new byte[0]);
    base.PreExecute();
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    this.Log("Entering PostExecute()", 0, new byte[0]);
    base.PostExecute();
}
```

I followed the [Ninja clicking method in SSIS Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068450/299327) to get the below logging working for a Script Task in the same SSIS Package.

```
public void Main()
{
    Dts.Log("Entering Main", 0, new byte[0]);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

I believe that I have SSIS Logging configured correctly since I see the "Entering Main" log entry.